# PyInstaller with Playwright and Firefox

Tags: python, firefox, playwright

I'm having trouble using PyInstaller to package a script that uses Playwright with the Firefox driver.

This is what the Python looks like (bare minimum):

```py
import time
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright, TimeoutError

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.firefox.launch(headless=True)
    
    context = browser.new_context(
        viewport={"width": 1280, "height": 900}
    )
    page = context.new_page()

    page.goto("https://www.python.org/")
    time.sleep(10)
```

I have installed Firefox:

```bash
PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH=0 playwright install firefox
```

And I wrap up the script using this:

```bash
pyinstaller -y --onefile tool.py
```

When I launch the resulting executable I get an error about missing `libmozsandbox.so`:

```
libmozsandbox.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

⚠️ If I replace Firefox with Chromium throughout then everything works fine. So this issue applies specifically to Firefox.

Things I have tried:

- installing Firefox with and without the `--with-deps` option;
- installing Firefox with and without `PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH=0`; and
- launching Firefox with the `--no-sandbox` argument by passing `args=['--no-sandbox']` to the `.launch()` method.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a very satisfactory solution, but I found that I could get this to work if I ran the process inside a `mcr.microsoft.com/playwright/python` container.

it also seems that this is the expected behaviour: "bundling OS dependencies is outside of the scope of Playwright" (https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-python/issues/2100). Weird that it works fine with Chromium but not Firefox.